# Pygame throws no errors but doesn't play any audio

Tags: python, audio, pygame

I am trying to use Pygame to play an .mp3 or .wav file. I want to do this on my Raspberry Pi 4 running Raspbian Buster, although the same test has been made on Windows and the same results occur:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()


audioFiles = [r'C:\pythonAudio\romeo&juliet.wav']

pygame.mixer.music.load(audioFiles[0])
pygame.mixer.music.play(0)
```

No errors are thown when I run this and the following is output to the console:

```
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
[Finished in 1.372s]
```

Am I missing something obvious? I have been using SimpleAudio as an alternative which works but is only compatible with .wav files as opposed to .mp3.

Comment: `...play()` only *starts* the music playing.  If the code exits immediately afterwards, you may not hear anything.

Answer (score 2):

The program ends as the music is being played in a different thread. In other words, `pygame.mixer.music.play(0)` will not wait for your song to finish but instead play it simultaneously with your program. Try:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()


audioFiles = [r'C:\pythonAudio\romeo&juliet.wav']

pygame.mixer.music.load(audioFiles[0])
pygame.mixer.music.play(0)

while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
    pygame.event.pump()
```

This will keep your program running until the mixer is no longer busy (no longer playing any music).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The program does not stop running but still, no audio is being played. I have tried both of these file formats with a different package (simpleaudio) and they work, so it is not the audio.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting it to an Ogg. Support for the other audio formats tends to be a bit inconsistent with Pygame.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and update this comment asap.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment above by [Kingsley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1730895/kingsley) :

> `...play()` only starts the music playing. **If the code exits immediately afterwards, you may not hear anything.**

Usually what we do is wrap the pygame.mixer in a GUI using something like `tkinter` so we don't get to face this issue. but since you want to run it like this then you can import the `time` module and you'll be able to play your music files :

```py
import pygame
import time 

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()


audioFiles = [r'C:\pythonAudio\romeo&juliet.wav']

pygame.mixer.music.load(audioFiles[0])
pygame.mixer.music.play(0)
time.sleep(10) # you can set this range according to your needs
```